# Polymer web app with Node.js not displaying page

Tags: javascript, node.js, polymer

The polymer app that I am working is not being displayed when I run `npm start`. There seem to be no errors on command prompt. How do I display my index.html properly? I am using Node.js to create a RESTful api to call the news api and the display the news on the web page. The web page is not being displayed at all.

**index.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="/bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents.js"/>
    <link rel="import" href="/bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
    <link rel="import" href="/bower_components/core-icon/core-icon.html">
    <link rel="import" href="/bower_components/paper-input/paper-input-decorator.html">
    <link rel="import" href="/bower_components/paper-icon-button/paper-icon-button.html">
    <link rel="import" href="/bower_components/paper-shadow/paper-shadow.html">
    <link rel="import" href="/bower_components/paper-card/paper-card.html">
    <link rel="import" href="news-api.html">
  </head>
  <body>
    <news-api></news-api>
  </body>
</html>
```

**app.js (Node.js)**

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var index = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.engine('.html', require('ejs').__express);
//app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);
app.set('view engine', 'html');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', index);
app.use('/users', users);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
// app.use(function(req, res, next) {
// var err = new Error('Not Found');
// err.status = 404;
//   next(err);
// });
//
// // error handler
// app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
//   // set locals, only providing error in development
//   res.locals.message = err.message;
//   res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};
//
//   // render the error page
//   res.status(err.status || 500);
//   res.render('error');
// });

app.listen(3000);
module.exports = app;
```

**index.js (Node.js)**

```
"use strict";

var express = require('express');
var NewsAPI = require('newsapi');
var router = express.Router();

let newsapi = new NewsAPI('MYAPIKEY');


/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index', { title: 'Hello' });
});

router.get('/trendz_now_global', function(req, res){

  // To query articles
  newsapi.articles({
    source: 'bbc-news', // required
    sortBy: 'top' // optional
  }).then(articlesResponse => {
    res.send(articlesResponse);
  });

});

module.exports = router;
```

**EDIT: Package.json**

```
 {
  "name": "trendz",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node app.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "~1.15.2",
    "cookie-parser": "~1.4.3",
    "debug": "~2.2.0",
    "express": "~4.14.0",
    "jade": "~1.11.0",
    "morgan": "~1.7.0",
    "serve-favicon": "~2.3.0",
    "newsapi": "~1.0.0",
    "ejs": "~2.5.2"
  }
}
```

Please pardon me if I have made some dumb mistakes. I just started working with Node.js

[image: File structure]

Answer (score 0):

You haven't let your app listen to any port. Add the below line just above the last line, then try `http://localhost:3000` after `npm start`.

Hope you have `node app.js` in your start command in `package.json` file.

```
app.listen(3000);
module.exports = app;
```

Comment: can you post your package.json file?

Comment: sure. Thanks for the help

Comment: Where is the `app.js` relative path from `package.json` since I can see the start command like this, `"start": "node ./bin/www"`

Comment: What do you mean? Are you asking for the location of app.js?

Comment: @NikhilRaghavendra yes

Comment: Its outside of all the folders it is in the same location as the package.json.

Comment: Change your start command like this `"start": "node app.js"`, then try `npm start`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127690/discussion-between-nikhil-raghavendra-and-aruna).